# Having trouble drawing a square grid for an android game

Tags: java, android, android-studio, grid

I would like for this to display as a 7 x 7 square grid in the centre of the screen, however as you can see with my current code the vertical lines are in the correct positions but the horizontal ones are not. I am sure this is a simple fix and any help would be appreciated -

```
public class GameGrid extends View {

    Paint black = new Paint();

    public GameGrid(Context context) {
        super(context);

        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        black.setStrokeWidth(8);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        float startX;
        float stopX;
        float startY;
        float stopY;

        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();

        int gridSize = 7;
        int gridSpacing = width / gridSize;

        //Vertical Grid-lines
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {

            startX = width / 2 - height / 2;
            stopX = width / 2 + height / 2;

            startY = i*gridSpacing;
            stopY = i*gridSpacing;

            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, black);

        }

        //Horizontal Grid-lines
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {

            startX = i*gridSpacing;
            stopX = i*gridSpacing;

            startY = height / 2 - width / 2;
            stopY = height / 2 + width / 2;

            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, black);
        }
    }
```

[Picture of what grid currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyIhS.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the offset (on both axis). Why you don't pre-calculate `xOffset` and `yOffset` and the start to paint based on the point `(xOffset, yOffset)`?

something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float startX;
    float stopX;
    float startY;
    float stopY;

    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();

    int gridSize = 7;
    int gridSpacing = Math.min(width, height) / gridSize;
    int boardSize = gridSize * gridSpacing;

    int xOffset = (width - boardSize)/2;
    int yOffset = (height - boardSize)/2; 

    //Vertical Grid-lines
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {

        startX = xOffset + i*gridSpacing;
        startY = yOffset;

        stopX = startX;
        stopY = startY + boardSize;

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, black);

    }

    //Horizontal Grid-lines
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {

        startX = xOffset;
        startY = yOffset + i*gridSpacing;

        stopX = startX + boardSize;
        stopY = startY;

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, black);
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure that will be always centered (e.g. in landscape ) you should set:

```
int gridSpacing = Math.min(width, height) / gridSize;
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for your answer, I have tried implementing your code into my project and it does now seem to have aligned the horizontal lines in the correct positions down the vertical lines, however only a very small part of them is visible suggesting either they are been drawn off the edge of the screen to the left, or that they are showing correctly but only a few pixels long

Comment: sorry, I fixed now, I was using `gridSize` instead of  `boardSize` in the `stopX`. should work now.

Comment: Thank-you much appreciated, only thing now is it needs one extra horizontal line along the bottom to close off the grid but sure I can hopefully work that one out

Answer (score 1):

I'd GUESS the problem is that the canvas isn't square?  Height is greater than width.

Thus in the vertical Gridlines

```
startX = width / 2 - height / 2;
```

gives a negative number and puts the starting point to the left off-screen. It looks fine, but the length is wrong.

For the horizontal Gridlines

```
 startY = height / 2 - width / 2;
```

is a positive number and you start partway down the screen.  Similarly, the `endY` value overshoots by some amount (note the horizontal gridlines are longer than the vertical gridlines as well as being offset downward)

Perhaps try

```
//Horizontal Y vals
startY = 0;
stopY   = height;
```

Comment: Thank-you however this just creates one diagonal line down from the top left hand corner towards the bottom of the screen

Comment: sorry, I fixed a typo: endY to stopY.  A diagonal also implies you made some other edit changing the X values....?

Anyway, I'd accept and use @leobelizquierdo 's solution.  It is much better than mine and makes the overall code more elegant and efficient.